# Manage Exceptions by custom message in Bean Validation API

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I am using Bean Validation API in my Spring-Hibernate Application. When user's input wrong value in `private Integer months;` in `MyBean class`, an Exception through and shows in error message like below...

[image: Message]

How can I customize this Exception message for user understanding. And how to force user input-value limited between 1 to 12.

Spring control `@ModelAttribute @Valid MyBean myBean`

Comment: Show your code/ work so far?